# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined while clicking on Navigation bar in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

While Clicking on drop down created in Navigation menu, it is throwing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined".
    can any one please help me to identify error.

{
Below is HTML Code
     
          
            
              Profound Software

// Some HTML code here

```
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#section1">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section2">Services</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Portfolio<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#section31">Animation</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#section32">WebSite Design</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#section33">Android Application</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#section4">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right top-right-padding">
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" ></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

```js
//java Script Code
          // Add scrollspy to <body>
          $('body').scrollspy({target: ".navbar", offset: 50});   
    
          // Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
          $("#myNavbar a").on('click', function(event) {
    
            // Prevent default anchor click behavior
            event.preventDefault();
    
            // Store hash
            var hash = this.hash;
            // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
            // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
            $('html, body').animate({
    
              
              
              scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            
    
    
            }, 800, function(){
           
              // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
              window.location.hash = hash;
            });
          });
```

}

Comment: What is the value of hash?

Comment: Jquery hash property returns the anchor part of a URL.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some of the HTML, my first guess is the hash is not a proper selector so its unable to get the element and calculate the offset.

Comment: have you checked the order of your js files? sometimes this can cause issues.

Comment: JS  files are in proper order , if we are not clicking dropdown in navigation menu, then exception will not occur.. so i think there is some thing wrong in while opening dropdown available in navigation menu

Answer (score 0):

i have added code to check hash value, if it is null then don't do nay thing.

```
 // Store hash
    var hash = this.hash;
   if (hash.length != 0) {

    // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
    // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
    $('html, body').animate({

      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top

    }, 800, function(){

      // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
      window.location.hash = hash;
    });
  }
```